# Split data into coulmn's on the basis of ; in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a csv file which contains 10000+ lines and i have to split those lines on the basis of semicolon (;). I am able to do this with space but i am not able to do it with semicolon (;). please, refer the below code and suggest the changes.

```
try{
   $lines = Get-Content "H:\Desktop\ASK_ME\ASKME\LERG1.DAT"
   ForEach ($x in $lines)
{
 $y = "$(($($x[0..3] -join '')).trim());$(($($x[4..53] -join 
'')).trim());$(($($x[54..75] -join '')).trim());$(($($x[76..83] -join 
'')).trim())"
$z = $y -join ';'
Write-Output $z | Out-File -FilePath "H:\Desktop\ASK_ME\ASKME\LERG.DAT" -
Append
}

$lines = Get-Content "H:\Desktop\ASK_ME\ASKME\LERG.DAT"
Write-Output $lines | Out-File -FilePath "H:\Desktop\ASK_ME\ASKME\csvsrg.csv" 
$excel=new-object -comobject excel.application

#Open Workbook Object
$workbook=$excel.workbooks.open("H:\Desktop\ASK_ME\ASKME\csvsrg.csv")

$excel.visible=$true
$worksheets=$workbook.worksheets
$sheet=$worksheets.item(1)
$sheet.activate
$range=$sheet.usedrange
$colA=$sheet.range("A1").EntireColumn
$colrange=$sheet.range("A1")
$xlDelimited = 1
$xlTextQualifier = -4142
$xlTextFormat = 2
#Convert Text To Columns
$colA.texttocolumns($colrange,$xlDelimited,$xlTextQualifier,$true,$false,$false
,$false,$true)
#AutoFit Columns
$sheet.columns.autofit()
#Ignore Prompt for Overwriting existing file
 $excel.displayalerts=$false
```

Comment: `Import-Csv -Delimiter ';'`?

Comment: I concur.  Why aren't you just using `Import-Csv` and using the output object to move into your excel spreadsheet?  P.S., there's this neat .net library and PoSh module for dealing with excel without the headache of the com object: [Link](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel)

Answer (score 1):

That is a cockamamie way to try to read a csv...

You can do this in two lines

```
$pathToCsv = "C:\path\to\file.csv"
$csv = Import-Csv $pathToCsv -Delimiter ';'
```

The output is stored in `$csv`

Answer (score 0):

Your cut or .dat file is Strange but if i keep your cut method, you can do it:

```
$delimiter=";"
$CSVFile="H:\Desktop\ASK_ME\ASKME\csvsrg.csv"

Get-Content "H:\Desktop\ASK_ME\ASKME\LERG1.DAT" | %{
[pscustomobject]@{
Col1=($_[0..3] -join '').Replace($delimiter, '').trim()
Col2=($_[4..53] -join '').Replace($delimiter, '').trim()
Col3=($_[54..75] -join '').Replace($delimiter, '').trim()
Col4=($_[76..83] -join '').Replace($delimiter, '').trim()
}
} | export-csv $CSVFile -notype -Delimiter $delimiter


$excel=new-object -comobject excel.application

#Open Workbook Object
$workbook=$excel.workbooks.open($CSVFile)
```

Comment: His method is not so bad. It avoids errors if the chain is not long enough, unlike a substring. I am surprised to see so many people tell others how to think, do, program ...

Comment: Apologies, I actually completely misread your code and misinterpreted the lesson you were teaching with processing the DAT file.

Comment: No problem, only intelligent people can recognize their mistakes because only in this way can we progress. Good day to you.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone trying this in the future and want to do it the way the OP wanted it to, i got it to work with a semicolon by doing what I did below.

```
$excel.visible=$true
$worksheets=$workbook.worksheets
$sheet=$worksheets.item(1)
$sheet.activate
$range=$sheet.usedrange
$colA=$sheet.range("A1").EntireColumn
$colrange=$sheet.range("A1")
$xlDelimited = 1
$xlTextQualifier = -4142
$xlTextFormat = 2
$semicolon = $true
$space = $false
$consecutiveDelimiter = $false
#Convert Text To Columns
$colA.texttocolumns($colrange, $semicolon, $xlTextQualifier, $space, $consecutiveDelimiter, $xlDelimited)
#AutoFit Columns
$sheet.columns.autofit()
#Ignore Prompt for Overwriting existing file
$excel.displayalerts=$false
```